# OSes considered "server" by NSIS LogicLib WinVer IsServer

Tags: nsis

What are the actual OSes that are considered a "Windows Server" by [`IsServer`](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/d72ae535f312858453ca0ce7001e5f87a46249db/Includes/WinVer/IsServer.md) of NSIS LogicLib WinVer?

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server) lists the following as belonging to the Microsoft Server family:

- Windows Server 2003
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows Server Essentials

But not:

- Windows Home Server
- Windows MultiPoint Server

Does `IsServer` share the same opinion?

The `IsServer` documentation also includes NT as a "server", contrary to the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Why do you care? Are you going to do something Active Directory related or some other operation that only works on a server?

Comment: @Anders Yes the software should only install on servers, 2003 and up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IsServer is true if OSVERSIONINFOEX.wProductType from [GetVersionEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx) is not VER_NT_WORKSTATION.

[NT4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT_4.0#Editions) and 2000 had both client and server versions of the OS.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724833(v=vs.85).aspx) claims you can detect home server by checking for the VER_SUITE_WH_SERVER bit but since the test for 2003 (`GetSystemMetrics(SM_SERVERR2) == 0`) is clearly wrong I don't know how much you could trust this information. (Checking for 2003 correctly means checking that the version is 5.2, not VER_NT_WORKSTATION (XP64) and only if you need to tell 2003R2 apart from 2003 would SM_SERVERR2 come into the picture)